# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) while fetching data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with contents like

```
verticalid  verticalname
1           Manufacturing
2           Pharma,Healthcare & Biotechnology
3           BFSI,telecome,Institutions
```

and I try to fetch data from this table with verticalid but, result is null. help me to solve this
query like

```
SELECT * FROM `verticalpublic` WHERE `verticalname`='Manufacturing';
```

Comment: How do you execute this?

Comment: this query execute in database

Comment: How? Using which client? MySQL client? phpMyAdmin? Using your own PHP script? Where do you see that there are zero records returned?

Comment: this error is only appeared by verticalname condition

Comment: mysql and also in my own php script

Comment: Are you sure there is matching data in your table?

Comment: yes i am sure ...while i am using vertical id as where condition then it will work fine

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have the correct schema enabled while executing this statement. Try clicking on the name of the schema, then clicking on the table before running the command.

See below example:
[image: See below example]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...can you explain??

Comment: i am using phpmyadmin(xampp)

Comment: @MaryReejoR I asked you how you run the query you never mentioned phpMyAdmin. When in phpMyAdmin you also must select the correct DB when executing the SQL.

Comment: I had assumed you were using workbench but no matter what you are using you need to do this.